# How to run a command for a deployed web application (Sencha) on a EC2 AWS?

Tags: amazon-ec2, cmd, extjs, command

I have a deployed Sencha web application on an EC2 instance and the database is running on RDS AWS. Now the application gives me an error that:

```
 Refresh required to update application
```

I know there is a command by Sencha Cmd `sencha app refresh` from this [Link](https://docs.sencha.com/cmd/guides/extjs/cmd_app.html#extjs-_-cmd_app_-_development_builds_and_refresh), but I don't know how to run this command on an already deployed application.

Is there a way to open a cmd command window like windows but on AWS to execute this command? Can you please help?

The EC2 instance is an Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS machine.

Comment: `sencha app refresh` is used to refresh your application for example after you add new classes. This should be done before deployment. But I think your issue is different. Can you add more details, what kind of error message do you get exactly?

Comment: Thanks. The problem is I modified the version string and one line in the code (main.js file) and pushed it to the repo. I know EC2 instance gets an update from bitbucket as soon as I pushed. However, the app doesn't show the changes and asks to refresh the application.  Maybe the application itself is required to refresh or reset to apply changes, but I'm not sure.

Comment: If you need `sencha app refresh`, I recommend running it locally and re-deploy app. If you run it only on the deployment server, your code will not contain these changes.

Comment: But still, depending on the exact error message, the issue might be something else.

Comment: You're right. I'm not sure as it's done by a former developer. Can you provide some information or link on how to deploy the sencha app to an EC2 instance? Any requirement or concern I should be aware of?

Comment: It doesn't really depend on where you deploy it. Normally you create a production build, for example `sencha app build --clean production`.  After this you have to copy the contents of `build/production` folder to you webserver.

Comment: `clean` switch is important so earlier generated files that were deleted for example will not be included in the build.

Comment: Thank you Peter